# Prove $E(E(Z|X, Y )|Y ) = E(Z|Y )$.

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, time-series

Let $(X,Y)$ be a random vector.

Prove $E(E(Z|X, Y )|Y ) = E(Z|Y )$.

I'm having a hard time understanding how to get this set up. I'm not sure how to set up the integrals for this. This proof was done in class, but I'm not understanding how to get it started and how to work with the integrals.

I know that there's many similar questions including this: [Conditional expectation property proof: $E(E(Z\mid X,Y)\mid X)=E(Z\mid X)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188903/conditional-expectation-property-proof-eez-mid-x-y-mid-x-ez-mid-x)

But I want to prove this from the definition of expectation with the integrals for $E(E(Z|X, Y )|Y )$ as was shown in class. I'm looking for an explanation on how the proof works and how the integrals lead to the result. $E(Z|Y)$

Comment: The definition of expectation via integrals will, if you unwind the meaning of all symbols in the linked proof (or in the proof on Wikipedia) give you a proof of the form you want. To make this a better question, you should first try that yourself and then ask about something *specific* if you have trouble converting (say) David's proof into an integral-based proof. Since $\Bbb E$ is just standing for an integral, this should be straightforward

Comment: It helps to consider that you should replace $X,Y$ by the $\sigma$-algebras they generate. Then use the very definition of $\mathbb E[Z|{\cal A}]\,.$